# React-native U.I Freezes and does not respond until you get response from axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I have one problem and have searched a lot and none of the solution is working for me on the forum.
I call 6 API's on the screen (there is no loader) and there is one button at bottom which navigates user to another screen.

i have added coded in componentDidMount() ,

```
 componentDidMount() {
            this.props.API1();
             this.props.API2();
         this.props.API3();
    }
```

However until i All three API's response comes in getderivedatatefromprops , the button at bottom used to navigate to another screen does not work.

this.props.API1() are redux actions defined as below

```
export const API1 = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        new Promise(async () => {

            const body = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: "get url of API",

            };
            axios(body)
                .then((response) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'GETRESPONSE',
                        payload: { response: response.data, error: false },
                    });

                })
                .catch((error) => {

                        dispatch({
                            type: 'GETRESPONSE',
                            payload: { response: error?.response, error: true },
                        });
                });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you are calling synchronous calls on the main thread. What does API1, 2, 3 look like?

Comment: This are the redux actions .  i have modified my code above to show how actions are mentioned in redux

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling async calls directly inside redux actions, which is not what redux was made to do.

You should use either [redux-sage](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) if that is what you want to do.

Also, I don't see in your design why you would want to make API1, 2, and 3 redux actions. Actions are meant to store date, not for triggering events that will store data. So you could just call the API calls, and then once they return send the data to redux.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is too late to answer but if somebody have this kind of problems just be sure if you do not have to many re-renders. Even if you read the documentation [React Native Performance Tips](https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#js-frame-rate-javascript-thread). There was written that too many re-renders will cause frames to be dropped.
Just make sure that you do not have to many re-renders, use Purecomponents and don`t change state on complex components many times. I hope it would be help full.